# python and join confusion

Tags: python

**Problem:** Write a function that will return a string of country codes from an argument that is a string of prices (containing dollar amounts following the country codes). Your function will take as an argument a string of prices like the following: "US$40, AU$89, JP$200". In this example, the function would return the string "US, AU, JP".

**Hint:** You may want to break the original string into a list, manipulate the individual elements, then make it into a string again.

**Input:**

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    values = ""
    price_codes = prices.split(',')
    for price_code in price_codes:
        values = value + price_code.strip()[0:2])

    return values


list1 = [ , ]

print(get_country_codes("NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5").join(list1))
```

Comment: This is not a coding service web page, comeback with specific questions and a code, show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Since some existing currencies have a three letters symbol, such as `CAD`, we have to expect an unknown number of characters before any amount.

```
def get_countries(s):
    countries = [c.split('$')[0] for c in s.split(',')]
    return ','.join(countries)

s = "US$40, AU$89, JP$200, CAD$15"

print(get_countries(s))
```

### Output

```
US, AU, JP, CAD
```

Alternatively, you can use `re` to simply remove anything following the country code in your string.

```
import re

s = "US$40, AU$89, JP$200, CAD$15"
countries = re.sub('\W\d+', '', s)

print(countries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
codes="NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"
get_country_codes=lambda c: ', '.join(e[0:2] for e in c.split(", "))
get_country_codes(codes)
```

Comment: Why not simply use def, a lambda is unnecessary here